# How do I keep my tab bar visible when segueing to another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

The problem I'm currently facing is that I would like to segue from the orange view controller to the yellow view controller by pressing on an icon on the top right hand corner of the orange controller. The issue that I am facing is that when I do click the icon in the simulator, it goes to the yellow controller but the tab bar disappears. How do I ensure the tab bar doesn't disappear when segueing to other views from views that are accessible from the tab bar? Thanks!

[image: Flowchart]

Comment: hello from SO! If you want to learn your solution as fast as possible then you should search "how to ask a question in stackoverflow?". but for now could you please provide your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your **Orange** `HomeViewController` inside a `UINavigationController` and embed this `UINavigationController` inside the `UITabBarController`. When you navigate from **Orange** to **Yellow**, you can push it on to the **Orange**'s navigation controller.

When you do a `push` call on the `UINavigationController` that's embedded inside the `UITabBarController`, it will keep the `TabBar` visible in the next screen.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! May I know what is the difference between wrapping and embedding? How do I wrap the orange controller inside a navigation controller? Do I then embed it into a **new** tab bar controller or the existing one that is above the orange controller?

Comment: There's no difference for this example. You can go to storyboard, select `HomeViewController` then go to bottom right corner of the storyboard - and `Embed In > Navigation Controller` like shown here - https://imgur.com/VIcjI9S

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to keep the tab bar visible on the yellow view controller but a new issue that I run into is that I now have 2 navigation bars ontop, the first one presumably being from then navigation bar that I set at the start. This is the flow of the entire app. May I know how I can rectify this issue? Thank you so much! 
https://imgur.com/sghY5IK

Comment: Okay, it seems weird. Do you have your `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController`? If YES, then what you need to do is - Remove that top level `UINavigationController` that contains `UITabBarController`. Repeat the answer configuration `Embed In > Navigation Controller` for the rest of your view controllers - `Search` & `Profile`.